# Call multiple event or a single event with multiple parameter

Tags: c#, custom-events

I have make a custom event like this:

```
public delegate void ResponseReceivedDelegate(string textToSpeak, string offeringText, string offeringImageNo, string animationName, string emotion);
public static event ResponseReceivedDelegate ResponseReceivedEvent;
 if (ResponseReceivedEvent != null)
    {
       ResponseReceivedEvent (textToSpeak, offeringText, offeringImageNo, animationName, emotion);
    }
```

and I have register this event into multiple other scripts, so that i know that this event has occurred.

Now the problem is, there are different parameters (as given above). My each script require a single parameter, rest parameters are not require for a particular script. Like one script is using textToSpeak, while another script using offeringText and so on . .  as the event fired. My question do i need to write seperate events or this one event is enough.? which is the correct way?

```
ResponseReceivedEventForSpeak (textToSpeak);
ResponseReceivedEventForOfferingText (offeringText);
ResponseReceivedEventForImageNo (offeringImageNo,);
//and so on...
```

or

```
ResponseReceivedEvent (textToSpeak, offeringText, offeringImageNo, animationName, emotion);
```

???????????

Comment: This is an opinion based thing - you can make an all encompassing one or you can have individuals.. its your design.

Comment: Maybe, but i think there is only one professional approach which i want to know with pros and cons.

Comment: "i think there is only one professional approach" - this too is opinionated.

Comment: If the events occurs at the same time, you could create one big event. I'd rather go for the standard way with a class derived from `EventArgs`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, as Jeroen wrote in his comment, using a class derived from EventArgs. In this class you can use an enum to specify what string is being passed:

```
public class ResponseReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        TextToSpeak,
        OfferingText,
        OfferingImageNo,
        AnimationName,
        Emotion
    }
    public ResponseReceivedEventArgs(EventType eventType, String eventValue)
    {
        Type = eventType;
        Value = eventValue
    }

    public EventType Type {get;}
    public String Value {get;}
}
```

Then you can use the same event for everything, while still sending only the relevant string, and keeping your code standards:

```
public delegate void ResponseReceivedDelegate(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs eventArgs);
```